# how would you combine set of mono string in web flux

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I have two following methods `Mono<Set<String>> researchTeamField = submissionService.findByResearchTeamField() //returns set of string` and  `Mono<Set<String>> reviewerTeamField =submissionService.findByReviewerTeamField() //returns set of reviewer string.` I want to combine the result of two set of string into one final mono set string. How can i do it?

Comment: Why not leave it as `Mono<Set<String>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip()` static method.
It merges given monos into a new Mono that will be fulfilled when all of the given Monos have produced an item, aggregating their values as defined by the combinator function.

```java
        Mono<Set<String>> mergeField = Mono.zip(researchTeamField,reviewerTeamField).map(d -> {
            d.getT1().addAll(d.getT2());
            return d.getT1();
        });
```